# Forcing node to not create a session in connect-mongo/connect-mongostore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

We are running on Amazon, using node with express, and connect-mongostore to manage the sessions. The load balancer sends a test to the servers every 15 seconds to make sure the app is alive. We have coded an API call for it to check, which tests if both node and mongo are working. However, this creates a session, with each call, as it's not a web browser, so a new session record gets built. We have 80,000 records in our session database, that expire every four weeks. Wondering if there is any way to prevent this happening, without having to hack either express or connect-mongostore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At one time you could ignore specific routes from connect's session management with  `connect.session.ignore.push('/individual/path')`, but this has been removed.

Why not put one public route <strike>app.get</strike>`app.use('/lbChck', function(req,res){ res.send(200);})` for the load balancer before `app.use(express.session(...));`?

Comment: Once you use a single route, `app.router` will get inserted into the middleware chain, effectively stopping `express.session` from being called for all other routes too. If you use `app.use` instead of `app.get`, it'll work though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: Just wanted to reply back again, just implemented this, and it works a treat. We may just be a bit too tightly wrapped, but that hit on the db every time is totally unnecassery.